# I was using X-Windows and accidentally pressed CTRL + ALT + 1 and it was locked out

Tags: process

I was working on X-Windows with graphics and then while changing terminal I accidentally press CTRL + ALT + 1 instead of CTRL + ALT + F1. My X-Windows locked out but still updating and displaying data, I just can't control it. My keyboard was still functioning so I changed the terminal and restart the X-Windows and it was working fine again. I Just wants to ask did someone knows about this functionality of x-windows or if yes how we can disable it so I dont use it accidentally. Also if some more examples of similar incident sharing will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SU. What OS are you using? No repro with Debian 11. Please note, this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site, so sharing experiences isn't how this works - unless it's done directly when providing answers to questions. As a new user it's a good idea to check the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), Asking and Answering in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) and some older questions with [accepted answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn how SE sites work.

Comment: Also please don't provide new info in comments, rather [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/742042/edit) your question so it gets more focused and everything relevant immediately available.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.